# Why am I getting "this.state is null" in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am brand new to Reacjs, I visited several question with a similar title but none helped me.

Why this code doesn't change my state?

```
 componentWillMount()
 {
     /** I am using superagent to fetch some data but it doesn't matter */

     var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=mykey";
     Request.get(url).then((response) => {

     this.setState({ messages: response.body.Search});


    });
  }
```

My render method

```
    render() {

         return (

                 <div>     
  <ListaMensagens  messages={this.state.messages}  /> this.state is null here.
                </div>
            ...
```

How can I change my state with the retrieved data and pass it to a child component?

Comment: did you defined the state in constructor? if not use `constructor(){ super(); this.state = { message: '' } }`. Also instead of making the api call inside `componentWillMount` use `componentDidMount `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use setState in componentWillMount without getting into trouble, BUT...

in your case you are setting the state after the response of the request which is causing problems.

Three solutions for your problem:

1: Use the constructor to initialize the state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        messages: []
    };
}
```

2: Fire setState in componentWillMount without waiting for any Promise

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        messages: []
    });
    request(...);
}
```

3: In the render function check if the state is set properly

```
render(){
    <div>
        { this.state && this.state.messages && <ListMensagens ... /> }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: By the way I prefer the second one because you don't need to add a new function (1st solution) and you get rid off business logic in the render function (3rd solution)